# Executing method once per wx.App.MainLoop execution without repeat wx.CallAfter calls

Tags: python, events, wxpython

I am using wxpython to create a GUI using the MVC design pattern.  I am using a state machine with the controller to track the state of the application and would like to execute the state transition method exactly once every time the `wx.App.MainLoop()` function runs.  I wanted this to execute in a consistent spot during the `MainLoop()` function so I would rather avoid threads or `wx.CallLater()`.

Is there a way to add a method permanently using `wx.CallAfter()` or similar method so that it is executed exactly once each time through the `MainLoop()`?

I have tried looking at the return object for `wx.App.GetMainLoop()`, but have had no luck finding out how to implement the functionality above using the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabye you think it more complicated than it is. Brute-force polling the GUI in its idle time is a recipe for high processor load. Presumably your program contains a GUI, the state machine and some input coming not from the GUI (e. g. from the network). Presumably your state machine will change state on three occasions:

1. The User enters something in the GUI
2. The internal state changes
3. External I/O (not over the GUI) is happening

For these cases you will/can do the following:

1. GUI input is event-driven: You decide, what user input you will consider as state-changing. This can range from clicking a `OK` button down to capturing `EVT_TEXT` or mouse events. No need to poll here.
2. Internal state change:

   - State change in event loop of state machine (if there is any). If there is a event loop in the state machine, you will need to spin it off in a separate thread, otherwise the GUI will block. You have to communicate back changes in the state machine in a thread-safe way to the GUI (far the easiest way is `wx.CallAfter`). See [the very helpful wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks).
   - Use a `wx.Timer` to call into the state machine every so often (e.g. every 100 miliseconds). In this case the state machine would not even require its own thread and thread-safe communication.
3. In principle the same thing as for point 2 can be done for I/O. Either spin off a thread or use a timer to regularily call into the I/O-machinery.

You can also bind to `EVT_IDLE`, which will be called every time no more events are pending in the event loop. But of course this will just lead to unecessary polling.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and complete answer nepix32!  That IS a very helpful wiki entry.